# Вывод данных mysql + php

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица "table" в ней столбик с данными.
и мне этот столбик нужно вывести с строку...

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table",$db); 
while ($myrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
$count = $myrow1['id']; 
echo "$count";
}
```

получается только тот же столбик(
На каждом кругу цикла, он делает его на новой строке /n. 
как сделать этот вывод в строчку?

Comment: Перед тем как погружаться в работу с СУБД бывает полезно разобраться в основах языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("select group_concat(id separator ' ') from table",$db); 
echo current(mysql_fetch_array($result1));
```

ну а если даже после этого у вас будет вывод в столбик, то это будет значить, что у вас в таблице записи с переводом строки в конце. и убрать его можно изменив запрос на

```
select group_concat(trim(trailing '\n' from 'id') separator ' ') from table
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать запросом:

```
select group_concat(столбик) from table;
```

Если нужно через пробел, то так:

```
 select group_concat(столбик separator ' ') from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table",$db); 
while ($myrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $count = $count.$myrow1['id']." "; 
}
echo "$count";
```

Comment: Ну я просил не сложить данные, а вывести в строку..

Comment: и мне нужно увидеть все данные которые в массиве, так что скобочку нужно после echo поставить

Comment: Забыл про особенности конкатенации. Обновил.

Comment: только вот Notice: Undefined variable: count in /var/www/localhost/htdocs/blog/reit.php on line 18
объявляю $count = 0; ошибки нет но этот ноль плюсуется к результату ...